# Achieving listview with bubble like badge on item type?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to achieve a customized `ListView` with every group of `ListView` items of the same type, there should be a button/bubble badge hovering above the first item of this group. It should look like this:

[image]

If possible I'd love to know how to switch the main bubble on the toolbar to change when the group of item type has been scrolled up and reached it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using an Image Button

Add the image you want the button to hold in
android:src=" "

Example of a layout using Image Button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.shakthivels.assignment_8.FormActivity"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    >


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Height"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Swag %"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onclickbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="DisplayName"
        android:contextClickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:onClick="RemoveFirst" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question